# How to get VSCode screencast mode to show question mark instead of SHIFT-/

Tags: visual-studio-code, screencasts

When I use screencast mode in Visual Studio Code and press `?`, instead of showing that I pressed `?` it says that I pressed `SHIFT` and `/` which is confusing, especially for people with keyboards in other languages where `/` and `?` are not on the same key.

How can I get VSCode to display that I pressed a `?` when I press a `?`, e.g. wait a second after the user presses SHIFT in order to display they key the user actually typed?

[image]

Comment: I would remove the part of you asking if there is other screencasting software.  I assume you are using the current November build?

Comment: And why? I mean, I would like to know, therefore I asked.

Comment: Questions seeking software recommendations are out of scope here at Super User.  You can certainly ask that part of the question, in another community, where they are allowed.  Have you reported this issue to the [Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) GitHub repository?

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks, I deleted that question, and I reported the issue at the VSCode GitHub repository.

Comment: This will either be a bug or be intended behavior, at least with regards to Visual Studio Code.  You might want to add which keyboard layout you are using.  It could be limited to a regional setting. The more information you provide the better changes we can submit an answer to your question.